# Two commentaries on the ir ha-nidachat

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, avodah-zarah, mishneh-torah

The Chabad translation of Mishneh Torah [includes](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912362/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Four.htm) an editor's note to Hilchot Avodat Kochavim 4 saying:

> There is a unique dimension to the laws of an עיר הנדחת that is not
> found in regard to any of the other prohibitions of the Torah. In this
> context, the city is considered as a single entity and the inhabitants
> and their property are not considered as individuals but as members of
> this wicked collective (Tzaphnat Pane'ach, Likkutei Sichot, Vol. 9).

Can anyone help point me towards where I can read the relevant passage in these two sources? Many thanks.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Tzafnat_Pa'neach_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.4.6.3?lang=bi

Comment: https://projectlikkuteisichos.org/

Comment: Note the Tzafnat Pa'neach generally writes very cryptically.

Comment: Thank you - hoping someone will be able to point me to the actual passages in question in each source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source from [volume 9 of Likkutei Sichot, parshat Ra’eh, pp. 107-114](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16027&st=&pgnum=135), beginning with the 2nd chapter is where the Rebbe discusses the view of the Rogatchover Gaon.

He is quoting the Rogatchover on the Torah to parshat Vayera 18:21, which appears on page 74 of volume 1 to Tzaphnat HaPane’ach al HaTorah.

[image: Rogatchover on Torah]

If you have trouble with the Yiddish, there is a book in English called, Torah Studies that was published in 1984 by Rabbi Jonathan Sacks of London. The relevant section appears there on pages 300-304.

Comment: See here for the English version (digital) of Torah Studies, Yaacov mentioned: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/110666/jewish/Torah-Studies-Reeh.htm

Comment: @Shmuel I was going to add that link but upon looking at it discovered that it is not the complete book and the relevant pages are not included there. It makes me wonder if the reprint removed parts from the 1984 original.

Comment: Okay, did not know that. Thanks for the update. I think it might be due to the fact that Chabad.org only has samples from the books, and not the complete books. They might have added in some samples from this book too?!

Comment: Relevant passage is actually on web here: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/110666/jewish/Torah-Studies-Reeh.htm

Comment: Many thanks! Appreciated

Comment: @Zarka It’s a pleasure to help. Thanks for the question.